# Prove this isomorphism about semidirect product $((\oplus_1^k \mathbb{Z}/2) \oplus \mathbb{Z}/n) \rtimes_{\varphi} \mathbb{Z}/2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, semidirect-product

Edited:
Considering the comments it turns out that my guess was true, and we have this isomorphism:

$$((\oplus_1^k \mathbb{Z}/2) \oplus \mathbb{Z}/n) \rtimes_{\varphi} \mathbb{Z}/2 \equiv (\oplus_1^k \mathbb{Z}/2) \oplus (\mathbb{Z}/n \rtimes_{\varphi} \mathbb{Z}/2), $$

but yet I have no idea how to prove this isomorphism. How can I prove this isomorphism?

---

Let $e, c$ be the elements of the cyclic group of order $2$, and let $\varphi_e(x)=I_N(x)=x$, and let $\varphi_c:N\rightarrow N$ be equal to $\varphi_c(x)=x^{-1}$.

I can show that the nontrivial semidirect product $\mathbb{Z}/n \rtimes_{\varphi} \mathbb{Z}/2$ is the Dihedral group $D_{2n}$. Also, I can show that $(\oplus_1^k \mathbb{Z}/2) \rtimes_{\varphi} \mathbb{Z}/2 \equiv (\oplus_1^{k+1} \mathbb{Z}/2)$, for any positive integer $k$.

What can we say about

$$((\oplus_1^k \mathbb{Z}/2) \oplus \mathbb{Z}/n) \rtimes_{\varphi} \mathbb{Z}/2?$$

What is this group? Is it isomorphic to

$$(\oplus_1^k \mathbb{Z}/2) \oplus (\mathbb{Z}/n \rtimes_{\varphi} \mathbb{Z}/2)\equiv (\oplus_1^k \mathbb{Z}/2) \oplus D_{2n}?$$

(If it is true then we should have $D_{4n} \equiv \mathbb{Z}/2 \oplus D_{2n}$ (for odd $n$), and some othe similar isomorphisms.) If the answer is no, then are there some conditios to have $$((\oplus_1^k \mathbb{Z}/2) \oplus \mathbb{Z}/n) \rtimes_{\varphi} \mathbb{Z}/2 \equiv (\oplus_1^k \mathbb{Z}/2) \oplus (\mathbb{Z}/n \rtimes_{\varphi} \mathbb{Z}/2)?$$

Comment: $D_{4n}$ has no non-trivial decompositions as a direct product.

Comment: @markvs So this means that my guesses were wrong, but yet I can not find $((\oplus_1^k \mathbb{Z}/2) \oplus \mathbb{Z}/n) \rtimes_{\varphi} \mathbb{Z}/2$ explicitly.

Comment: Try $n=2,3,4,5,6$.

Comment: The answer to your first question "Is it equal to ..." is yes. In fact $D_{4n} \cong C_2 \times D_{2n}$  when $n$ is odd, but not when $n$ is even.

Comment: Not really. I simply said that the answer to your first question is yes, irrespective of whether $n$ is odd or even. I didn't say anything about that implying anything.

Comment: Sorry I deleted my comment mistakenly, I write it again: @DerekHolt If $n$ is odd, then the answer to my first question is yes, which implies that $D_{2^k n} \cong C_{2^{k-1}} \times D_{2n}$, for any positive integer $k$ and any odd natural number $n$. Did I understand your comment correctly? But then it contradicts your comment about even values of $n$.

Comment: @DerekHolt My first question is: Is $((\oplus_1^k \mathbb{Z}/2) \oplus \mathbb{Z}/n) \rtimes_{\varphi} \mathbb{Z}/2$ equal to 
$(\oplus_1^k \mathbb{Z}/2) \oplus (\mathbb{Z}/n \rtimes_{\varphi} \mathbb{Z}/2)$? 

I think you said that we have the isomorphism $(\oplus_1^k \mathbb{Z}/2) \oplus (\mathbb{Z}/n \rtimes_{\varphi} \mathbb{Z}/2)\equiv (\oplus_1^k \mathbb{Z}/2) \oplus D_{2n}$ for all $n$. But you didn't comment on $((\oplus_1^k \mathbb{Z}/2) \oplus \mathbb{Z}/n) \rtimes_{\varphi} \mathbb{Z}/2 \equiv (\oplus_1^k \mathbb{Z}/2) \oplus (\mathbb{Z}/n \rtimes_{\varphi} \mathbb{Z}/2)$

Comment: But $C_n \rtimes_\varphi C_2 \cong D_{2n}$, so the two questions are equivalent. You keep telling me that I said things that I didn't say. I simply said that the answer to your first question is yes. (But in fact you should say "isomorphic to" rather than "equal to".)

Comment: @DerekHolt Sorry I did a big mistake, I assumed that: $D_{2^{k+1} n} \cong ((\oplus_1^k \mathbb{Z}/2) \oplus \mathbb{Z}/n) \rtimes_{\varphi} \mathbb{Z}/2$, which is wrong. Assuming this wrong assumption (!), then it is easy (!) to show that $D_{2^{k+1} n} \cong ((\oplus_1^k \mathbb{Z}/2) \oplus \mathbb{Z}/n) \rtimes_{\varphi} \mathbb{Z}/2 \equiv (\oplus_1^k \mathbb{Z}/2) \oplus (\mathbb{Z}/n \rtimes_{\varphi} \mathbb{Z}/2) \cong C_{2^{k}} \times D_{2n}$, which implies for example $D_{16}\cong C_2\times D_8$, which is wrong, sorry for everything and thaks for your patience.

Comment: @DerekHolt By my previous comment I mean: I realized where my problem was. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I did another mistake in my comment "Sorry I did a big mistake, I assumed that: ...": The last isomorphism in the long mathematical phrase should be written in this way: 
$$D_{2^{k+1} n} \cong ((\oplus_1^k \mathbb{Z}/2) \oplus \mathbb{Z}/n) \rtimes_{\varphi} \mathbb{Z}/2 \equiv (\oplus_1^k \mathbb{Z}/2) \oplus (\mathbb{Z}/n \rtimes_{\varphi} \mathbb{Z}/2) \cong C_{2}^{k} \times D_{2n}$$ 

Maybe it was better for me to rest today, and think another day.

Comment: I understand what you mean when you write $\oplus_1^k\mathbb{Z}/2\oplus(\mathbb{Z}/n\rtimes_{\phi}\mathbb{Z})$ since you gave me the homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Z}/2\rightarrow\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/n)$. However, I don't know what you mean when you write the other semi-direct product as you have not given me the homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Z}/2\rightarrow\text{Aut}(\oplus_1^k\mathbb{Z}/2\oplus\mathbb{Z}/n)$, is this just the same automorphism on each of the parts of the direct product?

Comment: @StevenCreech again call this group $N$, and again define $\varphi_e(x)=I_N(x)=x$, and let $\varphi_c:N\rightarrow N$ be equal to $\varphi_c(x)=x^{-1}$ (where $e, c$ are the elements of the cyclic group of order $2$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note in the below I shall use additive notation so $\phi_e(x)=x$ and $\phi_c(x)=-x$ as these are usually written as additive groups. I think the key observation is that if we let $(x,y)\in \oplus_1^k\mathbb{Z}/2\oplus\mathbb{Z}/n$ where $x\in \oplus_1^k\mathbb{Z}/2$ and $y\in\mathbb{Z}/n$, then $-x=x$, so $\phi_c((x,y))=(-x,-y)=(x,-y)$.

How about we just write down an isomorphism
$$\psi:(\oplus_1^k\mathbb{Z}/2\oplus\mathbb{Z}/n)\rtimes_{\phi}\mathbb{Z}/2\rightarrow\oplus_1^k\mathbb{Z}/2\oplus(\mathbb{Z}/n\rtimes_{\phi}\mathbb{Z}/2)$$
we note that an element of $(\oplus_1^k\mathbb{Z}/2\oplus\mathbb{Z}/n)\rtimes_{\phi}\mathbb{Z}/2$ can be written as a three tuple say $(x,y,z)$ where $x\in\oplus_1^k\mathbb{Z}/2$, $y\in\mathbb{Z}/n$, and $z\in\mathbb{Z}/2$. Then we shall let $\psi(x,y,z)=(x,y,z)$ as we have an element of $\oplus_1^k\mathbb{Z}/2\oplus(\mathbb{Z}/n\rtimes_{\phi}\mathbb{Z}/2)$ can also be represented by such a three tuple. We note that by definition, it is clear that this function is a bijection, and maps the identity to the identity. Thus, we just need to check that multiplication works out correctly. Thus, say we have $(x,y,z),(x',y',z')\in(\oplus_1^k\mathbb{Z}/2\oplus\mathbb{Z}/n)\rtimes_{\phi}\mathbb{Z}/2$, then
$$
\psi((x,y,z)+(x',y',z'))=\psi((x+\phi_z(x'),y+\phi_z(y),z+z'))=\psi((x+x',y+\phi_z(y),z+z'))=(x+x',y+\phi_z(y'),z+z')
$$
Similarly, we have that
$$
\psi((x,y,z))+\psi((x',y',z'))=(x,y,z)+(x',y',z')=(x+x',y+\phi_{z}(y'),z+z')
$$
Thus, we have that $\psi$ respects the group operation and we are done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.